# React devtool does not show reason why component rerendered

Tags: reactjs, react-devtools

The react developer tool used to show why a component was rendered, e.g. due to state change, context update or because of a rerender of the parent.
This information can not be found in the flamegraph anymore.

Did they remove it or are there some prerequisites in order for this information to be included?

[image]

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I found the solution by pure chance today. There is a checkbox hidden in the settings  on the profiler page which can be toggled to enable this setting..

[image: React Devtool]

Comment: Good lord that is dumb. Not sure why that's not checked by default. Thanks for updating with solution!